# VBA colour highlight based on IF

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to run the code below. It should be straight to the point, and I don't understand why it's not working. If cell b2 is "John", and cell O2 is empty, then O2 should be red. If O2 is not empty, then it should not be colored.

Any help is must appreciated.

```
Sub columnO(d As Long)

If Cells(d, "B") = "John" And Cells(d, "O") = "" Then    
    Cells(d, "O").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    Cells(d, "O").Interior.Color = RGB(1000, 1000, 1000)
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B10:O10000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    columnO Target.Row
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure how we are expected to understand why it's not working when we don't know what the problem is?

Comment: You want to look for cell "B2" when it's being modifed, but in your `Worksheet_Change` event, you are looking for `Range("B10:O10000")`, so "B2" doesn't trigger the event, since you start looking from row 10 (and not 2).

Comment: The problem is that if I write "John" in cell i.e. B2, and cell O2 is empty, it does not turn the cell O2 in red.

Comment: @georgec see my comment above, change to `If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B1:O10000"), Target) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @Shai Rado: yes, I changed the rage now to B2:O10000, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @georgec it works for me, maybe you have `Application.EnableEvents` turned Off. Restart Excel and see if it works

Comment: @Shai Rado: Yes, works now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done with conditional formatting. Just pick conditional formatting from Home menu on your ribbon --> new rule -->Use a formula to determine... and type formula

```
=$B$2<>"John"
```

Then you need only set your desired format. You may toggle with $ in formula to allow dragging and copying the format if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you rather use conditional formatting instead of VBA? 
Might be easier to manage

Comment: Flaniganga: Is because I want to learn VBA and all my work to be coded. Writing even simple codes, might help me to understand faster how codes work generally.